# SQL subquery to count how many people checked out of a hotel by day of week and by floor (SQLZoo)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working through one of SQLZoo's [hard assessment problems](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House_Assessment_Hard) and using MySQL. The booking data and database description can be found [here](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House).

> Check out per floor. The first digit of the room number indicates the
>   floor – e.g. room 201 is on the 2nd floor. For each day of the week
>   beginning 2016-11-14 show how many guests are checking out that day by
>   floor number. Columns should be day (Monday, Tuesday ...), floor 1,
>   floor 2, floor 3.

This involves the guest house database:
[image]

The **expected result**, which is not entirely correct as the left-hand column lists dates and not days):

```
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| i          | 1st | 2nd | 3rd |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 2016-11-14 |   5 |   3 |   4 |
| 2016-11-15 |   6 |   4 |   1 |
| 2016-11-16 |   2 |   2 |   4 |
| 2016-11-17 |   5 |   3 |   6 |
| 2016-11-18 |   2 |   3 |   2 |
| 2016-11-19 |   5 |   5 |   1 |
| 2016-11-20 |   2 |   2 |   2 |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

To tackle the problem, I'm trying to break it into subparts. For now, I want to generate a three-column table such as:

```
+------------+-----+------------+
| Date       | Floor| Checkouts |
+------------+------+-----+-----+
| 2016-11-14 |   1  |     5     |
| 2016-11-14 |   2  |     3     | 
| 2016-11-14 |   3  |     4     |
|     .      |   .  |     .     |
|     .      |   .  |     .     |
|     .      |   .  |     .     |
| 2016-11-20 |   1  |     2     |
| 2016-11-20 |   2  |     2     | 
| 2016-11-20 |   3  |     2     |
+------------+------+-----+-----+
```

At first glance, this seemed straightforward. The number of checkouts for  `2016-11-14` should be the sum of all occupants whose `booking_day + nights = 2016-11-14`.

My approach:

```
SELECT     a.booking_date AS 'Date',
           LEFT(a.room_no, 1) AS 'Floor',

           /* Sum the number of checkouts on a.booking_date, using an alias: */
           (SELECT     SUM(b.occupants)
            FROM       booking b
           /* Compare b.booking_date of these occupants against a.booking_date: */
           WHERE      b.booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY = a.booking_date) AS 'Checkouts'

FROM       booking a

/* Run through each date in the range */        
 WHERE     (a.booking_date >= '2016-11-14' AND 
            a.booking_date <= '2016-11-20')

/* Group checkouts by date and by floor */  
GROUP BY   a.booking_date, 
           LEFT(a.room_no, 1);
```

My code returns (i) the wrong checkout counts and (ii) the same count for all floors for a given day:

```
Date           Floor    Checkouts
2016-11-14       1         18
2016-11-14       2         18
2016-11-14       3         18
2016-11-15       1         17
2016-11-15       2         17
2016-11-15       3         17
```

Initially, I wondered if my `LEFT(a.room_no, 1)` wasn't working, giving me the total number of checkouts across all floors for a given day. However, the total number of checkouts for `2016-11-14` (across all floors) is `5 + 3 + 4 = 12` according to SQLZoo. I get `18`.

What's wrong with the reasoning behind my nested `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` category?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your question because I am not familiar with the booking data and also you never included it in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: sorry about that. I included the link to the webpage containing the booking data and database description on SQLZoo's website.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.  Stack Overflow questions need to be independent and you should not expect anyone to be familiar with SQLZoo's schema.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Understood. I posted because there were other similar SQLZoo questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, nights, booking_date)) AS week_number_checkout_date,
       DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, nights, booking_date)) AS week_day_checkout_date,
       LEFT(room_no, 1) [floor],
       SUM(occupants) checkouts
  FROM booking
 WHERE booking_date >= CAST('2016-11-14' AS DATE)
   AND booking_date <= CAST('2016-11-20' AS DATE)
 GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, nights, booking_date)),
          DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, nights, booking_date)),
          LEFT(room_no, 1)
```

Comment: I don't know how to test T-SQL but used this to write the MySQL version posted below. For the second line, do you mean to call the column checkout_day_name?

Comment: DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, nights, booking_date)) AS week_day_checkout_date -- I used the alias for the name of the day when the occupants checkedout

Comment: Have you tried the code? Do you still having some issue or does this resolved it?

Comment: Great! Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

- Mistake 1: not grouping by Floor and Date.
- Mistake 2: using `a.booking_date` instead of `(booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY)`

Solution:

```
SELECT
    (booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY) AS Date,
    LEFT(room_no, 1) AS Floor,
    SUM(occupants) AS Checkouts
FROM booking
WHERE
    (booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY) >= '2016-11-14' AND 
    (booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY) <= '2016-11-20'
GROUP BY (booking_date + INTERVAL nights DAY), Floor;
```

SQLZoo phrased the question incorrectly. Their answer lists the number of bookings that terminated for each day of the week, and not the number of occupants associated with those bookings.